# Getting different Pod status from "kubectl get pod" and "kubectl describe pod" command

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a Pod with two container – one container was successfully created, while other container failed.

Now, when I execute below command then I see that “Status” is “Error”:

```
C:\Users\test123>kubectl get pod pod3-two-nginx-containers-port-error
NAME                                   READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
pod3-two-nginx-containers-port-error   1/2     Error    0          134m
```

But when I execute below command then I see that "Status" is "Running":

```
C:\Users\test123>kubectl describe pod pod3-two-nginx-containers-port-error
Name:         pod3-two-nginx-containers-port-error
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:   Thu, 18 Mar 2021 12:50:19 +0530
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.0.9
IPs:
```

Why Kubernetes is showing wrong statuses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes is not showing the wrong status.

- From `kubectl get pod <<POD_NAME>>` command you get the Pod’s status.
- From `kubectl describe pod <<POD_NAME>>` you get the Pod **phase’s** status.

`kubectl describe pod` is giving you status as RUNNING because Pod has been bound to a node + all of the containers have been created + at least one container is still running. Read more about [Pod phases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase). Also read about [Pod conditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions).

`kubectl get pod` is giving you status as ERROR because Pod is not in healthy state. Right now I do not have link where you can read about what STATUS field means in `kubectl get pod` but probably I will find and share later.

Another way you can verify this is by running `kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running` command. If you get you Pod listed here then it is another way you can be sure of that status shown in `kubectl describe pod` command is Pod phase's status.

Comment: did you found out ?

Comment: @Ben nops. Actually didn't search.